# React dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in React:

```js
const TABS = [
    {
        value: "Names",
        label: "Names",
        onclick: (obj) => {
            tabOnClick(obj.value);
        },
        selected: mainTabSelected,
    },
    {
        value: "Logs",
        label: "Logs",
        onclick: (obj) => {
            tabOnClick(obj.value);
        },
        selected: mainTabSelected,
    },
    {
        value: "Groups",
        label: "Groups",
        onclick: (obj) => {
            tabOnClick(obj.value);
        },
        selected: mainTabSelected,
    },
    {
        value: "Subscriptions",
        label: "Subscriptions",
        onclick: (obj) => {
            tabOnClick(obj.value);
        },
        selected: mainTabSelected,
    },
]
```

I have tried to make the code dynamic, as the following:

```js
const values = ["Names","Logs","Groups","Subscriptions"];
const labels = ["Names","Logs","Groups","Subscriptions"];
const TABS = [
     {
         value: {values},
         label: {labels},
         onclick: (obj) => {
             tabOnClick(obj.value);
         },
         selected: mainTabSelected,
     }]
```

Am I right?

Comment: `values: {values}` is straight JavaScript, the `{values}` thing isn't a JSX expression (because you're not in a JSX context). In an object literal, that just creates a property on the object called `values` that has an object that, itself, has a property called `values` that refers to the array of values.

Comment: I would save confusion in future if you used different values in the `labels` array and the `values` array so people don't assume that only one array is needed.

Comment: Why do you have separate arrays for values and labels if [you want value and label to be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74653446/react-dynamic-variables/74653504?noredirect=1#comment131769395_74653504)?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
const values = ["Names", "Logs", "Groups", "Subscriptions"];

const TABS = values.map((e, i) =>
    {
        return {
            value: e,
            label: e,
            onclick: (obj) => {
                tabOnClick(obj.value);
            },
            selected: mainTabSelected,
        }
    }
)
```

This would map on each element on your values array and inject new object on the Tabs array for each tab.

Comment: The value and the label should be the same. For example value: "Groups", label: "Groups"

Comment: @Konstantinos edited to use only one array's value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same `label` and `value` array then you can do this with a single array as:

```
const labels = ["Names", "Logs", "Groups", "Subscriptions"];
const TABS = labels.map(label => ({
    value: label,
    label,
    onclick: (obj) => {
        tabOnClick(label);
    },
    selected: mainTabSelected,
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to make the code dynamic, as the following:
>
> ...
>
> Am I right?

Not quite, you've confused JSX expressions and JavaScript property shorthand notation, because they both use the form `{___}`. But that's only a JSX expression when you're in a JSX element (for instance: `<div>{"this is a JSX expression"}</div>`). Where you're using it, you're just in a JavaScript object literal. So what you have creates an array with a **single** element in it, a single object that has:

- a `value` property which is an object with a `values` property referring to your `values` array
- a `label` property which is an object with a `labels` property referring to your `labels` array
- ...and the `onclick` and `selected` properties

In other words, your code produced something that looked like this:

```
// The structure your original code produced
const TABS = [
    {
        value: { values: ["Names", "Logs", "Groups", "Subscriptions"] },
        label: { labels: ["Names", "Logs", "Groups", "Subscriptions"] },
        onclick: (obj) => {
            tabOnClick(obj.value);
        },
        selected: mainTabSelected,
    },
];
```

Instead, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want one of two things:

1. An array of objects, where each object takes its `value` and `label` from an entry in those arrays. (But [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74653446/react-dynamic-variables/74653504?noredirect=1#comment131769395_74653504) you've said the `value` and `label` should be the same, which is confusing — why have separate arrays? But I'll discuss that below.)
2. To use those arrays to render tabs in a React component.

If you're rendering tabs in a React component, there's no need for an intermediate array of tab information like `TABS`. But first I'll address creating `TABS`, then I'll address using the array(s) in a React component to render tabs.

#### Creating the `TABS` array (if needed)

You could use a simple loop:

```
// Note: Assumes `values` and `labels` are the same length
const TABS = [];
for (let n = 0; n < values.length; ++n) {
    const value = values[n];
    const label = labels[n];
    TABS.push({
        value,
        label,
        onclick: (obj) => {
            tabOnClick(obj.value);
        },
        selected: mainTabSelected // <== Not sure what this is
    });
}
```

But a call to `map` would be a bit more concise:

```
// Note: Assumes `values` and `labels` are the same length
const TABS = values.map((value, index) => ({
    value,
    label: labels[index],
    onclick: (obj) => {
        tabOnClick(obj.value);
    },
    selected: mainTabSelected // <== Not sure what this is
}));
```

In both cases, if you want `value` and `label` to be the same as [you mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74653446/react-dynamic-variables/74653504?noredirect=1#comment131769395_74653504), just get rid of your `labels` array and use `value` for `label`. For instance, with `map`:

```
const TABS = values.map((value) => ({
    value,
    label: value,
    onclick: (obj) => {
        tabOnClick(obj.value);
    },
    selected: mainTabSelected // <== Not sure what this is
}));
```

And in all of those cases, there's no need for the `obj` parameter and `obj.value`, you could just use `value` directly, since the function closes over the `value` for each iteration:

```
    onclick: () => {
        tabOnClick(value);
    },
```

#### Using the array(s) to render in React

You've edited your question to mention React, though. If you want to use the array(s) to render elements in a React component, there's no need for the `TABS` array at all. Just use the array(s) directly.

To do that, you'd probably want to create a `Tab` component to handle rendering a single tab. Here's an example:

```
const Tab = ({ value, selected, onSelected }) => {
    return (
        <div className={`tab ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`} onClick={() => onSelected(value)}>
            <span className="marker">{selected ? "➔" : ""}</span>
            {value}
        </div>
    );
};
```

The `Tab` component expects its value, a flag for whether it's selected, and a function to call if it's clicked (to select it). (The marker could be supplied by CSS if you prefer.)

Your component using it might look like this;

```
const Example = () => {
    const [mainTabSelected, setMainTabSelected] = useState(values[0]);
    const tabOnClick = (value) => {
        console.log(`Tab clicked: ${value}`);
        setMainTabSelected(value);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {values.map((value) => (
                <Tab
                    key={value}
                    value={value}
                    selected={value === mainTabSelected}
                    onSelected={tabOnClick}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Live example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const values = ["Names", "Logs", "Groups", "Subscriptions"];

const Tab = ({ value, selected, onSelected }) => {
    return (
        <div className={`tab ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`} onClick={() => onSelected(value)}>
            <span className="marker">{selected ? "➔" : ""}</span>
            {value}
        </div>
    );
};
const Example = () => {
    const [mainTabSelected, setMainTabSelected] = useState(values[0]);
    const tabOnClick = (value) => {
        console.log(`Tab clicked: ${value}`);
        setMainTabSelected(value);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {values.map((value) => (
                <Tab
                    key={value}
                    value={value}
                    selected={value === mainTabSelected}
                    onSelected={tabOnClick}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.tab {
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tab .marker {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

In those examples, I've used `value` as the value and label of the tab, because (again) of [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74653446/react-dynamic-variables/74653504?noredirect=1#comment131769395_74653504). But let's suppose you wanted to have separate values and labels. You wouldn't want to have two separate arrays for it, parallel arrays are problematic (it's easy to add something to one but not the other). Instead, you'd want an array of objects with `value` and `label` (or you might even make `label` optional, note `"Subscriptions"` below):

```
const tabInfo = [
    { value: "Names", label: "The Names" },
    { value: "Logs", label: "Some Logs" },
    { value: "Groups", label: "Groups Of Stuff" },
    { value: "Subscriptions" },
];
```

Then your `Tab` component would accept an optional `label` prop, which it could default to `value`:

```
const Tab = ({ value, label = value, selected, onSelected }) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return (
        <div className={`tab ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`} onClick={() => onSelected(value)}>
            <span className="marker">{selected ? "➔" : ""}</span>
            {label /* <−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− */}
        </div>
    );
};
```

The component using it would map through `tabInfo`:

```
            {tabInfo.map(({value, label}) => (
                <Tab
                    key={value}
                    value={value}
                    label={label}
                    selected={value === mainTabSelected}
                    onSelected={tabOnClick}
                />
            ))}
```

Live example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const tabInfo = [
    { value: "Names", label: "The Names" },
    { value: "Logs", label: "Some Logs" },
    { value: "Groups", label: "Groups Of Stuff" },
    { value: "Subscriptions" },
];

const Tab = ({ value, label = value, selected, onSelected }) => {
    return (
        <div className={`tab ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`} onClick={() => onSelected(value)}>
            <span className="marker">{selected ? "➔" : ""}</span>
            {label}
        </div>
    );
};
const Example = () => {
    const [mainTabSelected, setMainTabSelected] = useState(tabInfo[0].value);
    const tabOnClick = (value) => {
        console.log(`Tab clicked: ${value}`);
        setMainTabSelected(value);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {tabInfo.map(({value, label}) => (
                <Tab
                    key={value}
                    value={value}
                    label={label}
                    selected={value === mainTabSelected}
                    onSelected={tabOnClick}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.tab {
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
    color: black;
}
.tab .marker {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```